# Does CPU matter when rendering with GPU?

Tags: rendering, performance, hardware

A bit of context: I've got two graphics cards (not in the same build, my motherboard cannot support that), a GTX 1060 and a GTX 960. I use the 1060 for most rendering and gaming and such, but the 960 is just collecting dust. I'm gonna get a PC from my school that I want to install the 960 into and use it as a rendering machine, but of course since it's a school PC the processor will be pretty bad. Will this low-end processor bottleneck my 960's rendering significantly? Or will the difference be minimal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  GPU rendering is just that.  CPU will have little to no effect - pretty sure.
I am a little hesitant if system memory plays a role if you run out of graphics card memory, that could be an issue, but I'm not sure about that.

Comment: The CPU *is* used considerably while rendering even through GPU. It is used to pre-process all data, animations, export scene into graphics card memory prior to rendering, and also do all the rendering work the GPU can't. If you open the task manager while GPU rendering you will notice it constantly uses a variable amount of processing resources. That being said it is a lot less demanding than the task of actual rendering, and will likely have a smaller impact on overall speed.